# Renaming Windows.old to windows

Tags: windows

In my laptop's old hdd. There are windows.old and windows folders.windows.old belongs to win7, windows belongs to win10. However, win10 does not start. I connnected hdd externally to another pc. What happens if I delete windows folder and rename windows.old to windows.
Will old operating system(win7) work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not. However, you can use cmd from ISO to rename user folder and do a clean install.

```
cd /d C:\
move C:\Users C:\U /Y
move C:\ProgramData C:\D /Y
rd C:\Windows /S /Q
rd C:\Program Files /S /Q 
rd C:\Program Files (x86) /S /Q
```

Note: DO NOT FORMAT